# How to change variable inside a class and return it

Tags: python

In this Test class, I want to change the value of the variable count, cross, and circle.

```
cross = False
circle = False
count = 0

a = 'cross'


class Test:
    def testing(self):
        global count, cross, circle
        count += 1
        if a == 'cross':
            cross = True
        elif a == 'circle':
            circle = True


Test()
print(cross)
print(circle)
print(count)
```

What I want the output printed:

```
True
True 
1
```

But instead:

```
False
False
0
```

You see, the changing variable inside the Test class seems no effect to the variable itself. How can we actually change the variable globally so it will be printed as what I expected (note: this changing variable thing really must be in that same class)?

Comment: You never call the method... Also your logic says circle _shouldn't_ change.

Comment: The *whole point of classes* is to avoid mutable global state. *Don't modify global variables from within a method*. Uses *class state instead*

Answer (score 3):

It simple bro
You are Calling a class and you are changing the variables in `method` try:

```py
test=Test() #creating instances
test.testing() #calling method
print(cross)
print(circle)
print(count)
```

And its not recommend changing `variables` in `global`

Comment: Oh, I see. Previously I thought the most important part here is global, but it's not even needed and recomendded.

Comment: Yes also creating a class its recomendded to create dunders like: `__init__`

Answer (score 0):

The problem of this code is that you initialize the class, but you don't call it's `testing` method. Even if you only coded one method into the class, it will not be automatically called for you. Instead, when you construct an object from the `Test` class (with `Test()`), the class's `__init__` method is called - the constructor method. Every class has one, even if you didn't code it yourself - Python inserts one for you if you don't. So, you either have to assign your `Test` object to a  variable and call the variable's `testing` method:

```py
# variables, class definition …
test = Test()
test.testing()
# prints …
```

or directly call the object's `testing` method:

```py
# variables, class definition …
Test().testing()
# prints …
```

or define your own constructor and call the `testing` method from there:

```py
cross = False
circle = False
count = 0

a = 'cross'


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.testing()
    
    def testing(self):
        global count, cross, circle
        count += 1
        if a == 'cross':
            cross = True
        elif a == 'circle':
            circle = True


Test()
print(cross)
print(circle)
print(count)
```

But in fact, if you want to modify global variables, you don't need a class - just move your `testing` function out of the class and call it directly, or use a class - but then you don't need global variables and you should rather make them *attributes* of your class, like this:

```py
cross = False
circle = False
count = 0

a = 'cross'


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cross = False
        self.circle = False
        self.count = 0
        self.a = 'cross'
        
        self.testing()
    
    def testing(self):
        self.count += 1
        if self.a == 'cross':
            self.cross = True
        elif self.a == 'circle':
            self.circle = True


test = Test()
print(test.cross)
print(test.circle)
print(test.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually call the testing() method, you only define it using `def testing():`

Afterwards, in the class you can just type testing() to basically call the function, and that should fix your problem. But also, your expected outcome is also impossible, because `a` cannot be both `cross` and `circle`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I made a mistake, what I meant is:
True
False
1

Comment: The thing is I just wanna make one of the variable changed